# ¿Como puedo automatizar Excel para que copie estadísticas de la MLB?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, aplicación-web

Por el momento este es el código Excel-VBA que tengo para copiar los datos de la WEB, pero aun necesito copiar los datos de las paginas siguientes y no consigo el código para dar clic a los diferentes botones o enlaces.

```
Sub GetHTMLDocument()

    'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As Object
    Dim y As Integer

    'start a new browser instance
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'make browser visible
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate to page with needed data
    objIE.navigate "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&ts=1526432697176"
    'wait for page to load
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
    y = 0

    'look at all the 'tr' elements in the 'table' with id 'myTable',
    'and evaluate each, one at a time, using 'ele' variable
    For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("datagrid"). _
      getElementsByTagName("tr")
        'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
        Debug.Print ele.textContent
        'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
        'put text of 1st 'td' in col A
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
        'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
        'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
        'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(5).textContent
        'put text of 4th 'td' in col f
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y).Value = ele.Children(22).textContent
        'increment row counter by 1
        y = y + 1
           Next

    'save the Excel workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: La web en la que navegas tiene varias hojas. Tendrás que o bien hacer clics en esos elementos o jugar con las url. Fíjate que tu URL inicial acaba en `&page=1&ts=1526461217534`. Ahí tienes el elemento `page` y una fecha en [milisegundos Unix](https://currentmillis.com/). Con estos dos factores, puedes jugar para crear un Loop que vaya abriendo todas las páginas y copiar lo que necesites.

Comment: Disculpe, pero no se como hacer dicho loop, lo que necesito es que alguien me ayude a completar el código, si esta a su alcance por favor colaborarme con alguna referencia o completar el código estaría enteramente agradecido de usted.

Comment: Aquí ayudamos a desarrolladores, no trabajamos gratis. Dices *que alguien me ayude a completar el código*. Y se te ha dicho una posible solución, solamente tienes que programarla. Pero si no sabes VBA, me temo que tendrás que contratar a algún desarrollador que te lo programe. Si tienes alguna duda **concreta y específica**, puedes preguntar. Pero una pregunta en plan **trabajan para mí gratis** me temo que no es posible.

Comment: Le presento mis disculpas de la manera mas sincera, disculpe si mal interprete las condiciones de esta web, pasa que el proyecto no es para tercero este es un proyecto personal y en el lugar en donde vivo es muy difícil o casi imposible encontrar personas con el conocimiento sobre estos temas quisiera aprender sobre vba y si esta a su interés quisiera platicar sobre si puedo contratarle para este asunto. Gracias de antemano

Comment: No te disculpes. Yo también fui algo rudo y punto. Le daré una vuelta a tu código a ver si se me ocurre algo, pero, de verdad amigo, le sugiero aprender VBA para sacarle el máximo partido a Excel. Hay muchísimos cursos online y videotutoriales donde empezar

Comment: Tomare muy en cuenta su sugerencia, he querido aprender vba ya estoy en eso. Aunque la verdad no se por donde empezar por lo amplio que es ese mundo de los códigos se que  suena muy perezoso de mi parte pero si me recomendaría por donde empezar no se quizás contarme sobre su experiencia y como aprendió usted, estaría súper en deuda con usted.

Comment: Hay un par de cursos de iniciación muy buenos, y que explican las cosas fáciles, y en español. Yo los usé mucho en el pasado para tener una base, y luego ya es simplemente practicar, mirar en foros, youtube, etc. Pero necesitas los conceptos básicos. Aprender vba lleva su tiempo, pero merece la pena mucho. Un curso que me gustó mucho es http://neckkito.xyz/nck/index.php/manuales/47-curso-vba  y el otro, aplicado a Excel, es https://excelyvba.com/curso-de-vba/. Te recomiendo ambos, de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

este no es mi mejor código, pero creo que te puede servir para volcar resultados.

simplemente he hecho un bucle Do Loop para que vaya cambiando de página. Esto a veces volcará los mismos datos, pero luego limpiamos quitando duplicados.

Espero que te sirva como punto de partida.

```
Sub GetHTMLDocument()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim EstaPagina As Byte
Dim EstaURL As String


'Página inicial

EstaPagina = 1
'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
y = 1

EstaURL = "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=" '&ts=1526432697176"

'start a new browser instance
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
'make browser visible
objIE.Visible = False

Do Until EstaPagina = 255
    'navigate to page with needed data
    objIE.navigate EstaURL & EstaPagina
    'wait for page to load
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'If UCase(Left(EstaURL, 211) & "1") = UCase(Left(objIE.LocationURL, (211 + Len(EstaPagina)))) And y > 1 Then Exit Do

    'look at all the 'tr' elements in the 'table' with id 'myTable',
    'and evaluate each, one at a time, using 'ele' variable
    For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("datagrid").getElementsByTagName("tr")
        'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
        'Debug.Print ele.textContent

        'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
        'put text of 1st 'td' in col A
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
        'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
        'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
        'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(5).textContent
        'put text of 4th 'td' in col f
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y).Value = ele.Children(22).textContent
        'increment row counter by 1
        y = y + 1
    Next

    EstaPagina = EstaPagina + 1

Loop

objIE.Quit

Set objIE = Nothing
Set ele = Nothing

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), _
    Header:=xlNo


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Volcado terminado", vbInformation
Range("A1").Select

    'save the Excel workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Estoy en deuda con usted señor Elier Sánchez E-Infantes, me ha servido de mucho su colaboración así que cuando decida tomarse unas vacaciones por el caribe espero tome en cuenta una isla del caribe "República Dominicana" acá tiene una amigo.  Estoy tomando los cursos que me refirió porque aún tengo que copiar los "split" de la web (vs surdos, vs derechos, etc) y con este código no lo hace en fin. Mis disculpas al administrador   por este comentario tan extenso y felicitaciones por reunir a tantos desarrolladores que son magnificos.

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar un selector CSS para obtener el número de páginas y luego recorrer hasta la última página.

---

**[Selector de CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):**

`.paginationWidget-last`  es un selector de CSS. `"."` significa clase.

Elemento html seleccionado con css:

[image: elemento html]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, numPages As Long
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2018&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&ts=1526432697176"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim ele As Object, t As Date
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.querySelector(".paginationWidget-last") '<== obtener elemento con el último número de página
            '.paginationWidget-last   es un selector de CSS. "." significa clase
            If Timer - t = 10 Then Exit Sub
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        numPages = ele.innerText

        For i = 1 To numPages
            'tu codigo
        Next i

        .Quit '<== Recuerde salir de la aplicación
    End With
End Sub
```